# How to rename a groovy method which has a literal name in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Groovy allows us to define this nice function:

```
def "my nice function"() {
    //impl
}
```

and call it later like this:

```
"my nice function"()
```

How can I refactor the code in IDEA and rename this method? Usual rename (Shift+F6) creates a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, I've reported it in YouTrack, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-170254](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170254) Problem renaming Groovy methods with literal names

Comment: You might want to comment the ticket that renaming should also work for single quotes.